# How to catch the MouseHover event for QSystemTrayIcon?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need to do some action, when my mouse cursor hovers system tray icon. I've tried to solve this, with

```
connect(trayIcon, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), this, SLOT(testinAgain(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));

void MainWindow::testinAgain(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
    if (reason == QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick)
        QMessageBox::information(this, "test", "test");
}
```

But there are no one thing, that i need in QSystemTrayIcon.

I've tried to search it in Qt documentation, but i found nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an [event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter). Check for the hover event.

Comment: There is no cross-platform solution for the hover event of QSystemTrayIcon, yet (Qt5.7). You are lucky, when you are on X11: `Only on X11, when a tooltip is requested, the QSystemTrayIcon receives a QHelpEvent of type QEvent::ToolTip. Additionally, the QSystemTrayIcon receives wheel events of type QEvent::Wheel. **These are not supported on any other platform.**`